# OpenCV Kalman Filter, erasing from std::vector

Tags: c++, opencv, exc-bad-access, kalman-filter

I have this problem, see.

I'm using OpenCV to track a hand in a video. The hand in located with a CascadeDetector and then tracked using CamSHIFT. I'm also using a Kalman Filter, to correct the position of the hand, if the CamShift algorithm fails at some frames.

The problem arises, when I'm trying to erase an element from a std::vector, where I'm storing my Hands. The reason for erasing is that due to some issues, a face is misinterpreted as a hand, so I'm detecting faces, and if the hand region intersects with a face region, I delete that hand. I know, very naive, but I'm currently at the very start. 
The code looks like this:

```
class Hand {
...
public:
    struct 
    {
        ...
        struct {
            cv::Mat_<float> measurement;
            cv::KalmanFilter KF;
            cv::Mat state;
            cv::Mat processNoise;
        } KalmanTracker;
    } Tracker;
};
...
std::vector<Hand> hands;
...
std::vector<cv::Rect> faces;
faceCascade.detectMultiScale(frame, faces, 1.1, 2, CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT);
// iterate through hands
for (std::vector<Hand>::iterator it = hands.begin(); it != hands.end(); ++it) {
    // iterate through faces:
    for (std::vector<cv::Rect>::iterator fc = faces.begin(); fc != faces.end(); ++fc) {
        cv::Rect intersection = (*it).handBox.boundingRect() & (*fc);
        // check if they have at leasy 75% intersection
        if (intersection.area() >= ((*it).handBox.boundingRect().area() * 0.75)) {
            // delete that hand from list
            hands.erase(it);    // this gets me a a EXC_BAD_ACCESS
        }
    }
}
```

The `hands.erase(it)` line gets me an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` while pointing at my `KalmanFilterTracker` struct, as well as this line in `mat.hpp` with a `EXC_i386_GPFLT`:

```
inline void Mat::release()
{
    if( refcount && CV_XADD(refcount, -1) == 1 ) // EXC_BAD_ACCESS, code=EXC_i386_GPFLT
    ...
}
```

Neither `hands` nor `faces` are empty.
If I completely remove the Kalman filter from my project and any mention or use of it, the error disappears.

Comment: you can't reuse the old iterator after erasing from the vector.

Answer (score 1):

vector::erase(iterator) invalidates the iterator being erased. But it does return a new iterator to the next valid item in the vector. Thus the line should be:

```
it = hands.erase(it);
```

**Edit after berak's comment:**

Ah, I missed the inner loop. Since you're invalidating `it` inside the inner loop, things get a little complicated. You'll need to jump through some hoops to get it right.

```
for (std::vector<Hand>::iterator it = hands.begin(); it != hands.end(); ) {
    bool found = false;
    // iterate through faces:
    for (std::vector<cv::Rect>::iterator fc = faces.begin(); fc != faces.end() && !found; ++fc) {
        cv::Rect intersection = (*it).handBox.boundingRect() & (*fc);
        // check if they have at leasy 75% intersection
        if (intersection.area() >= ((*it).handBox.boundingRect().area() * 0.75)) {
            found = true;
        }
    }

    if (found) {
        it = hands.erase(it);
    }
    else {
        ++it;
    }
}
```

It's possible to fold some of the iterator manipulation into the inner loop, but keeping it outside makes the code a bit clearer and easier to reason about.

Comment: Changed the line, but the error persists. I suspect that the error is not with the iterator itself, but has something to do with the Kalman Filter instance.

Comment: @Gnagn, unfortunately it's not as simple as that. since it's in the inner loop, it would require another it != hands.end(); check after that (if the last item of the vector got removed, it==end() now)

Comment: But this way in the `if (found)` statement it is a valid iterator, and then before next loop you increase it again. You miss one doing this way, or I'm wrong?

Comment: @Jepessen, Oops. Is that better now?

Comment: I think yes. I've said that because maybe it were related to the error, considering that I did not understand well what's the error... :(

Comment: @Jepessen Given the OP's answer, that the vector was empty when he went to erase the iterator, the original error was that he was erasing iterators in the inner loop, which was allowing the vector to empty because it was never hitting the `it != hands.end()` condition in the outer loop. This new code (hopefully) avoids that.

Comment: Indeed. I already solved the problem by adding a bunch of if(hands.size()<2 || it == hands.end()) everywhere, but your solution seems to be much more elegant. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, through some debugging I found out, that my vector of hands becomes empty at some point and the error appears while trying to erase from an empty vector.
Only thing left is to find out why does it become empty and at which point.
Thank you everyone.